# HTML/CSS page not expanding

Tags: html, css

im creating a backend for my web app, and im with a problem related to the html/css, i will post images, its more easy to understand what is happening.

Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9LRv.png

Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjhej.png

I need some tips to fix this problem, if possible.

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2v3L5zqL/2/)**

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
     $('right-side').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=200px');
 });
```

Thank you!

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: "i will post images, its more easy to understand what is happening." No, images are nice to look at and may supplement the problem description, but you need to explain the problem in greater detail, and more importantly, post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Sorry for the fiddle, its fixed.

add the overflow: scroll; fixed the problem, i realy miss that one tho

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem right, you want to set the overflow of `.right-side` to `scroll`.

```
.right-side {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2v3L5zqL/4/

The problem is that your content overflows the height of the website, which is 100% of the viewport height. So you have to control the overflow.

I also think it would be better practice to not set the body height to 100%, but instead fix the sidebar to the right side by using `position: fixed`...